# Parse unknown keys from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Have a firebase database that is being updated by a remote device and another side that has to be listed, the data comes, but I do not know how could I use Firebase reflection to parse the  list of objects as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `oxygen_level` is a direct child of `Firebase root`, to display those values, please use the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference oxygenLevelRef = rootRef.child("oxygen_level");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String oxygen_mg = ds.child("oxygen_mg").getValue(String.class);
            String sensor_status = ds.child("sensor_status").getValue(String.class);
            String time = ds.child("time").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", oxygen_mg + " / " + sensor_status + " / " + time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
oxygenLevelRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```